# Find the minimum weight cycle that contains a specific edge

Tags: algorithm, graph

given a graph:
- oriented,
- strongly connected and
- weighed (the weights are all positive)
I have to write a function that taken as input an edge (u, v), calculate the weight of the cycle of minimum weight that contains this edge.

I thought I'd do as follows but the procedure is inaccurate and incomplete:
- Starts a bfs visit starting from node u
- Keep in a variable the temporary weight
- When you arrive to v choose the minimum of the previous weights.
How do I keep track of previous weights? How to write the pseudocode?

I have no idea how to get started so someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be reduced to [Shortest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem):

Find the shortest path from `v` to `u`, then the shortest cycle that contains `(u,v)`, is `v->...->u->v`, where `v->...->u` is the shortest path from `v` to `u` as found by the shortest path algorithm.

It can be solved efficiently using [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), since there are no negative weights in the graph.

**Correctness Proof:**

Assume there is a cheaper cycle  `v1->v2->...vi->u->v->v_i+1->...->vn->v1`. Let's say it weights `x < d(v,u) + w(u,v)`

Since it's a cycle, we can look at it as `v->v_i+1->....->vn->v1->...->vi->u->v`.

The weight of the cycle didn't change, and is still `x`.  This means `x=w(v,v_i+1) + ... + w(vn,v1) + ... + w(v_i-1,vi) + w(vi,u) + w(u,v)`

But this gives us `w(v,v_i+1) + ... + w(vn,v1) + ... + w(v_i-1,vi) + w(vi,u) + w(u,v) - w(u,v) < d(v,u)`, and we have found a shorter path from `v` to `u`, than `d(v,u)`, which is contradicting correctness of Dijkstra's Algorithm.

QED

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I apply dijkstra to find the shortest path between u and v then I apply again dijkstra to find the shortest path between v and u? Am I right?

Comment: @user3808470 No, you need only shortest path from `v` to `u`. The path from `u` to `v` must use the edge `(u,v)`.